# AJAX callback not firing

Tags: jquery

So, I have the following function. On click I send some data via AJAX to ampther page that posts  i to my db. That part works fine. However, I need to remove a row in my table on successful db insert. I've attempted to use .done() but for some reason it's not firing. Is there trigger I need to execute of the other PHP page to let this script know that it was a successful operation?

```
$(document).on('click', '.send', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input:not(.ofrCode)').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).parent().addClass('has-error');
        }
    });
    if (!$(this).closest('tr').find('td').hasClass('has-error')) {

        var code = $(this).closest('tr').find('.item').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  '/myPage.php',
            data: {
                'code' : code
            },
            dataType : 'json',
            async: false

        }).done(function() {

            $(this).closest('tr').remove();

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: `async: false` --- why do you need that? Is HTTP request performed successfully?

Comment: 1) Why `sync: false` and 2) try adding `.fail(function (data) { console.log("error", data); })` to see if it's failing

Comment: Note that using `.done()` with `async: false` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.

Comment: @barmar Thx. What should be used instead?

Comment: @elzi I get no errors. Response code 200.

Comment: @santa The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) answers that: **As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, in combination with @Papa and @elzi 's suggestions I got it to work by changing the following:

```
var src  = $(this),
    code = src.closest('tr').find('.item').val();

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  '/myPage.php',
        data: {
            'code' : code
        },
        dataType : 'json',
        statusCode: {
            200: function() {
                src.closest('tr').remove();
            }
        }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` is incorrect as the context won't be the same when the ajax call is returned.

You need to save `this` to a variable before the ajax is called.

```
var source = $(this);
```

In the callback for ajax use:

```
source.closest('tr').remove();
```

Comment: Hmm... didn't really help. Sorry.